# Why isn't my button translating correctly in my div?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and attempting to replicate [this button effect](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate3) in a project of mine where the buttons are children of a div. However, whenever I do the `translateY`, my buttons move to the side instead. Here is the HTML and CSS; button-2 is the problematic one:

```css
.container {
  position: relative width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: ridge;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

#button-1:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

#button-1:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  box-shadow: 0px 9px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 62%;
  left: 50%;
  /* if i remove this line, translation works as expected
           but then the button is no longer centered horizontally
           consequently, keeping the line breaks the affect
           but the button can be centered horizontally
        */
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#button-2:hover {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#button-2:active {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px gray;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Button - "Pressed Effect"</h2>
<div class=container>
  <button id="button-1">Btn1</button>
  <button id="button-2">Btn2</button>
</div>
```

The problem seems to stem from `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`, which is what I have to do to center button-2 horizontally in the `container` div. I can remove that line and the effect works, but then button-2 is no longer centered horizontally. Why is it that `transform: translate(-50%, 0);` seemingly causes the subsequent `transform: translateY(5px);` not to work for button-2? Is there anyway I can horizontally (but not vertically) center button-2 while also being able to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: it is not done by translating but by increasing the `margin-top` (Well it should be done)

Comment: use flexbox to position your container and buttons, not absolute positioning.

Comment: @tacoshy Thank you, just tried this and it worked. Why is this though? Why won't translating (at least for button-2) work?

Comment: Changing `transform: translateY(5px);` to `transform: translate(-50%, 5px);` (last line in your CSS) seems to bypass the issue. But the other comments should be taken into account.

Comment: @DeusDev Interesting. I've read that `transform` can create a new containing block; if this is true, could that be why the `translateY(5px)` seems "off"? So button-2 is being translated down 5px, it's just being translated in a new block that doesn't account for the initial -50% translation of button-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the translate property on the second button becoming active, you overwrite the original transform which is moving the button by half its width in the negative X direction.

It is important to keep this translation as well as the new one so make the translation in the active state set both the X and Y values that you want.

```css
.container {
  position: relative width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: ridge;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

#button-1:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

#button-1:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  box-shadow: 0px 9px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 62%;
  left: 50%;
  /* if i remove this line, translation works as expected
           but then the button is no longer centered horizontally
           consequently, keeping the line breaks the affect
           but the button can be centered horizontally
        */
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#button-2:hover {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#button-2:active {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px gray;
  transform: translate(-50px, 5px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Button - "Pressed Effect"</h2>
<div class=container>
  <button id="button-1">Btn1</button>
  <button id="button-2">Btn2</button>
</div>
```

Note: as others have suggested you may like to look into using flex (or grid) to position your buttons rather than having to mess around with positioning using absolute and translations. The translate for Y could then remain as in the original and you wouldn't be translating in the X direction at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the line ` transform: translate(-50px, 5px);` in your code, is there a reason you use -50px instead of -50%? They both seem to work the same, just wondering if there's any advantages/disadvantages to either.

Comment: Apologies, it should be -50%. Thanks for spotting it. Only worked with the px value because the width was 100px.

Answer (score 0):

you have gotten your X and Y axis mixed up.

you translated via `translate(-50%, 0)` which moves it by an X of -50% and a Y of nothing, you can fix this by changing it to `translate(0, -50%)` which will move it down a Y of -50%, and an X of 0.

test the snippet:

```css
.container {
  position: relative width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: ridge;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

#button-1:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

#button-1:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  box-shadow: 0px 9px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 62%;
  left: 50%;
  /* if i remove this line, translation works as expected
           but then the button is no longer centered horizontally
           consequently, keeping the line breaks the affect
           but the button can be centered horizontally
        */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

#button-2:hover {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

#button-2:active {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px gray;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Button - "Pressed Effect"</h2>
<div class=container>
  <button id="button-1">Btn1</button>
  <button id="button-2">Btn2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The X and Y axes are not getting mixed up. But the X translation is getting lot when the Y translation is introduced.